# Allow for more delimiters in display names

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, display-names, localization, international-sites

Currently, we can use a half-width space  and a half-width hyphen `-` in our display name (username) as a delimiter.

However, there are more delimiter symbols commonly used in the international community. For example, these two delimiters are very popular in the Japanese community.

- a full-width space
- a full-width middle dot `・`

For now, if we try to include these letters in our name, the site says the following error:

> Display Name can only contain letters, digits, spaces, apostrophes or hyphens and must start with a letter or digit

I want to change this behavior. How about adding more delimiters for the international community? At least, I want to add the two delimiters above for the Japanese community.

(By the way, a user in SOja community noticed an interesting behavior: we cannot use single full-width space `山田　太郎` but we *can* use two successive full-width spaces `山田　　太郎`. So it may be a bug that we cannot use a full-width space.)

<sub>Context: Originally, [a related bug report was posted to Stack Overflow for Japanese](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2893/19110) and got a lot of votes, so I post an edited report here in English.</sub>

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is a full-width space so common? Is it an online phenomena, or are larger spaces also common in written text?

Comment: @ert In Japanese we commonly use full-width letters "こんにちは、世界" ("Hello, World" in Japanese) so we usually use full-width spaces. By default, the full-width one is input when pushing the space key by Japanese IME. It is hard for me to determine whether we use full-width spaces in written text because there are no clear distinction between half-width and full-width in written text. But for example we use larger spaces when writing on [Genkō yōshi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genk%C5%8D_y%C5%8Dshi) (see the embedded image).

Comment: I see no problem with this, looks like a reasonable request.

Comment: These delimiters should be available on all the sites in the network, not only on international ones. Users are allowed to use Japanese usernames everywhere, so it makes sense to let them use proper delimiters

Comment: To clarify: In this request I want to allow the delimiters on *all* sites. Title was edited by someone.

Comment: nekketsuuu you should be able to [rollback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/342382/revisions) to the correct version.

Comment: Those are separators not delimiters.  A separator falls between a pair of elements, whereas a pair of delimiters surrounds a single element.  Sepa-raters vs [delimiters].

Comment: @tchrist [nit] What about a comma in CSV? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter

Comment: @nekketsuuu Notice how it's a CSV file with *Comma **Separated** Values*, not a CDV file with *Comma **Delimited** Values*? :)

Comment: @tchrist https://stackoverflow.com/q/9118769/5989200

Comment: @nekketsuuu The selected answer is wrong. The one below it is right. Words have meaning, and it is useful for different words to have different meanings because this provides for more nuanced technical discourse. The string `:foo:` has 3 fields if it is colon-separated, 1 if colon-delimited, and 2 if colon-terminated.

Comment: @tchrist No, I don't want to discuss details in comments because its preciseness is not very important here. Also please read a comment of the second answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The full-width space and will-width middle dot characters are now allowed in display names on all sites.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe this error message should be modified, too: `Display Name can only contain letters, digits, spaces, apostrophes or hyphens and must start with a letter or digit` (By the way this "letters" contains several CJK characters and others. So how about changing this sentence to warn only about symbols?)